# Controller does not open in CodeIgniter

Tags: .htaccess, codeigniter, controller

I have three controllers in CodeIgniter application - `i`, `login` and `test`.

All controllers perfectly work with `/APP/index.php/` path - I can open `/APP/index.php/i`, `/APP/index.php/login` and `/APP/index.php/test`.

Controllers `i` and `login` work without `index.php` as well - `/APP/i` and `/APP/login` (I have a modified `.htaccess` file).

Controller `test` does NOT work without `index.php` - I get 404 error when I open `/APP/test`.

`i` is the default controller, but `login` is not default and it works (I thought it could be the problem).

When I added the 4th controller it also didn't work without `index.php`.

It gets even more weird - sometimes I can open `/APP/test/some_function` (and sometimes I cannot) and after this I can even open `/APP/test`. But then I cannot open it again this way. `index.php` way works all the time. `Test` controller has a really simple code...

So my question is what can possibly go wrong here and how can I make my controllers accessible without `index.php`?

Thank you very much for your help.

Below is my `.htaccess` file, I think the problem can be there:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /APP/

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^system.*
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^application.*
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L]

</IfModule>

<IfModule !mod_rewrite.c>
    ErrorDocument 404 /index.php
</IfModule>
```

Comment: You don't happen to have a directory named `test` as a neighbour to index.php, do you?

Comment: Have you set `$config['index_page'] = '';` in `config.php` file.

Comment: No, I do not have a directory `test` (you mean top level index.php, correct? No such directory anyway... Good idea btw, I would've never guessed to check). And yes, `$config['index.php'] = ''`... Thank you.

Comment: @esp set logging to debug level and check the logs, see if you can get any clues by reading it

Comment: Thank you very much. I now understand where the problem was.
Actually, when you access the controller without `index.php` file, the main application folder becomes case-sensitive (`APP` in my question). As I have a much longer application folder name and it has both lower and upper case letters, I just had it typed with one letter in the wrong case. For the default controller it does not matter and other controllers were accessed via the links where the case was correct. And as `test` was accessed directly, this wrong case was giving me 404 error. Via `index.php` path, the case doesn't matter.

Comment: Probably I can remove this case sensitivity via some edits of `.htaccess`, but it is not so important. Thank you very much.

Comment: What does your routes.php file look like, seems like you've left out some routing.

Comment: As I wrote above, the problem was with myself (my comment above). Routes.php is standard - only default controller is there. I just don't know how to close the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I now understand where the problem was, thanks to [@w0rldart](/users/971392/w0rldart) suggestion.

Actually, when you access the controller without `index.php` file, the main application folder becomes case-sensitive (`APP` in my question).

As I have a much longer application folder name and it has both lower and upper case letters, I just had it typed with one letter in the wrong case. For the default controller it does not matter and other controllers were accessed via the links where the case was correct.

And as `test` was accessed directly, this wrong case was giving me 404 error.

Via `index.php` path the case of the main application folder doesn't matter.